Failed to Load d:\test\SNI.dll system componentmodel.win32Exception: The specified model could not be found
There are many solution in root folder and each solution has .Net Framework 4.7.1 MVC web Project and has API and library project target both .Net Framework 4.7.1 and .Net Core 6.0 .
when I migrated API and library project that target .Net 6.0 to .Net 8.0.
The Azure CI/CD pipeline which deployed earlier has x64 folder with sni.dll but after migration it is not generating this folder.
The VS 2022 configuration manager has Any CPU for all projec. The local VS2022 before and after migration, it generate the x64 and x86 folder with SNI.dll but Azure devops ci is generate the these 2 folder before migration but after migration it is not generating.
The MVC web is not loading and give error 500 internal server error if we look into the actual error "Failed to Load d:\test\SNI.dll system componentmodel.win32Exception: The specified model could not be found "
Azur CI TASK used to build is MSBUILD@1
Added /p:Platform=x64 but this was not work since configuration manager for that project is ANY CPU. May be if I change this to X64 it may generate but I don't want to .
Please advise how to have these files on Azure ci/cd deployment.

Please collect MSBuild bin logs from both scenarios, and compare them. That contains all the details to get you started, https://msbuildlog.com/

@Lex Li,
I saw build log before and after migration has copy fil sni.dll to respective bin\x64 but it is not in artifact zip file which publish does

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#unable-to-load-native-sni-server-name-indication-library

Are you using a self-hosted agent or a Microsoft-hosted agent to run the pipeline? If it's a self-hosted agent, is it the same one where you run the local VS2022? If not, you can configure a new agent on it and see if it works. If it's a Microsoft-hosted agent, please ensure that the vmImage is set to windows-latest with VS2022.

I also found this question related to the SNI.dll for your reference. Maybe you can try setting the flag IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract to true and see if it can work around the issue.

I see only difference is pool agent from windows-2019 to windows-2022 / windows-latest. Some library/API migrated from .Net core 6 to .Net 8. but the MVC Web App is still 4.7.1. I tried to build 2019 with migrated solution (ie some library migrated to .net 8 and main MVC is still in 4.7.1) but getting error on build and installed .net 8 but still it try to build on .net 6 and give error. the problem is SNI.dll is not getting deployed in bin/x64/sni.dll ater updating the agent pool to latest or windows 2022

Thanks for your update. Could you please also try to configure a self-hosted agent on the one where you run the local VS2022 successfully? This can help narrow down the issue.

By the way, can you please share the full YAML and the current published artifact file list to better check the issue?

Added CopyFile task to copy the SNI.dll to staging in CI and Copied that file into bin\x64\ in CD. but my concern why on the last agent windows-2022, PublishBuildArtifact is not deploying this as [art of zip file.

Hi @user3497702, so you added the Copy File task to copy the SNI.dll as workaround. Does it work now? I can understand that you have concern about the issue. As I mentioned in the previous comment, can you please share the full YAML or try to configure a self-hosted agent to better check the issue? Otherwise, it's hard to find the cause of the issue from the existing description.

I cannot share YML here and cannot use self hosted agent. Thanks  Miao Tian-MSFT for the response.

Hi @user3497702, it's OK, and I can understand. I noticed that you said, "I saw build log before and after migration has copy sni.dll to respective bin\x64 but it is not in artifact zip file which publish does". So, the sni.dll is created. What is the path of it? What is the target folder of the publish artifact task? Does the path/folder of publish artifact task contain the sni.dll file?

When I update the agent pool to windows-2019, it generate the sni.dll as build output. but if I have windows-2022, it is not generating. We have referred Microsoft.Data.Sqlclient 1.1.3 version referred.
